# How to choose a specific value from a loop to be plotted against a range of values?

Tags: matlab

I cannot think of the proper wording for this, but I am trying to have my code run a loop that will input a value of X into an initial condition variable. This variable is then inputted into the heat equation to be plotted. From the code I want to choose a value which is at X(i=51) and plot it as T(x,T1). As i said before I don't know the proper wording to search for a possible solution. Any advice would be great!

```
clear;
clc;
% initialize given variables
A= 0.25;
L= pi;
Nx=101; Nt=10^(-4);
dx=L/(Nx-1);

T1=zeros(1,Nx);
x=linspace(0, L, Nx); %x distance

%Initial condition
%T1 will be the "new" T value and To will be the old
T1= x.*(pi-x);
%For plotting, time starts at 0.
t=0;
for n=1:50
    To=T1;
    t=t+1;
    for i=2:Nx-1
        T1(i)=To(i)+Nt *A*((To(i+1)-2*To(i)+To(i-1))/(dx^2))+ sin(5*x(i));
    end
    %B.C given than @ T(0,t) & T(L,t) = 0
    T1(1)=0; T1(end)=0;
    figure(1)
    plot(x,T1); set(gca, 'ylim',[-110 110]);
    ylabel('Temperature along the Rod');
    xlabel('Location on the Rod of length Pi');
    title(sprintf('Time = %f seconds', t));
    pause(0.001);
end
```

The expected out put that I want to plot is `plot(x(i=51),T1)` which would show an image just like this. For this plot I ran my code and altered i to =50:51 to get the needed values for the heat equation. I am trying to have this be plotted in the code shown and not have to rewrite my code over and over to get different plots because I change values such as i or time  ect...[image]

Comment: If you don't know how to explain it, take that as a sign that your explanation will be hard to interpret by others... In this case a picture might be worth a thousand words, [edit] your question to include the expected output, and add a comment at which point you want it to happen. Why does the current output not suit your needs?

Comment: @Wolfie sorry about that hope this helps!

Comment: Does the following solve your issue? `figure(2); hold on; plot( x(51), T1(51), '.' ); hold off;` inside the `n` loop (before/after your current plotting code)? i.e. do you want the plot for all `n`, for only `x(51)`?

Comment: Yes I want to plot all values over time for only x= value at (51), so would it be plot( x(51), T1) since the T1 will change over time but the x value stays constant?

Comment: `T1` is an array though, `x(51)` is a scalar... how do you expect that plot to look? Does the code I suggested not work (if not please say why)?

Comment: You are correct sorry about that! Thank you very much for assisting I get the correct plot

Comment: Good to hear, I've added an answer for you to accept if it works, which offers two similar solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You want to plot a consistent value of `x`, specifically `x(51)`, for every `n`.

This can be done a couple of ways

First, as individual points with `hold on`:

```
for n = 1:50
    % ... calculation ...
    hold on
    plot( x(51), T1(51), '.' );
    hold off
end
```

You could update the plot, this will be quicker to compute and has the advantage of showing a line plot

```
x_51 = NaN( 50, 1 );
T1_51 = NaN( 50, 1 );
p = plot( [], [] );
for n = 1:50
    % ... calculation ... 
    x_51(n) = x(51);
    T1_51(n) = T1(51);
    set( p, 'XData', x_51, 'YData', T1_51 );
end
```

Comment: I am a bit confused on how to set up the second solution. I would like the line graph but when implementing this I am not getting a graph.

Comment: Have you tried literally copy and pasting the code I've written, including your processing code where I left the "calculation" comment? Do you get an error or just an unexpected result?